# In the milky way which star(s) are farthest from galactic plane?

Tags: galaxy, milky-way

I am looking for at least one star on each of the side of the galactic plane. I understand there would be an error tolerance. So, please do not hesitate if the answer is not exact.  Preferably, please refer to a paper. I searched on the internet and only found the farthest stars from the earth.
By "in the milky way" I mean any star that rotates around the center of the milky way. Among (stars of) satellite galaxies of milky-way, the confirmed galaxies that are rotating around milky-way exclusively are included.

Comment: Define "in the Milky Way".

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I think this would be very difficult to answer. Any assessment would have to define where the boundary of the galaxy lies. Multiple papers might have multiple different boundaries. Most stars in the universe could be farthest from the plane, do you mean inside the galaxy and farthest from the plane? Also, this question is probably better fit for SE Astronomy.

Comment: @BMFForMonica Yes. I mean inside the galaxy.

Comment: @RussellBorogove Any star that rotates around the center of the milky way is "in the milky way".

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellite_galaxies_of_the_Milky_Way

Comment: This can't be answered.

Comment: What Rob said. The earlier version was already difficult: large parts of the Milky Way are unobservable, and spotting stray stars on its fringes and determining their exact 3D location is very hard. But it's even worse now that you're including satellite galaxies.

Comment: @PM2Ring I understand Rob comments better after your explanations.